# Comparing rank-deficient matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two $3\times 3$ matrices each of rank 2.

1. How can I check that they are equivalent?
2. What definition of equivalence is there in this case?

Comment: Element-by-element equivalence I assume.

Comment: Same characteristic polynomials is necessary condition for equivalence.

Comment: @Phonon, if the third row is simply 3 times the second row in one of the matrices, then element-by-element equivalence won't help.

Comment: So... you need to check whether they are equivalent, but you don't know the definition of "equivalent"? You'll have a very hard time checking it, then!

Comment: As an initial guess, I thinking "equivalent" means having the same column space.  Just a guess.

Comment: Maybe [this concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence)?

Comment: If Dylan has found the right concept, then note that it says there that two matrices of the same (size and) rank are guaranteed to be equivalent, thus answering the questions.

Comment: @Dylan, that seems quite good for equivalence. Or I might go with Sasha's or Michael's approach. I'll try them out and see which one I like (Yes, it's that flaky of a definition...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer for three conceivable notions of "equivalence":

1. To find out if the matrices have the same row (column) space, compare the reduced row (column) echelon forms.
2. Usually, matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same dimensions are called *equivalent* if there are invertible matrices $S$ and $T$ such that $A = SBT$.
   Two matrices of the same dimensions are equivalent iff they have the same rank.
   So without further computations, your two rank 2 matrices are equivalent.
3. Another related notion is *similarity*: Two $n\times n$ square matrices $A,B$ are called *similar* if there is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix $S$ such that $A = SBS^{-1}$. Two matrices are similar iff they have the same rational normal form. In the case that your base field is algebraically closed, you may also compare the Jordan normal forms.